# Disabling CSS rules

Tags: css, kendo-ui

Is there any way to disable a CSS rule?

I ask because I am using Kendo UI, and their rules are very all-encompassing, eg:

```
.k-grid td
{
   // styles
}
```

However if I put my table inside their table it will be styled up similarly, so its affecting far too much and needs to be removed/replaced. I don't want to have to manually overwrite the rules and keep up to date with any of kendo's changes. I don't want to have to manually delete it every time I update kendo files either.

Any chance of an easy fix? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no better way to disable a CSS rule for an element that is matched by that rule except by overwriting everything the rule defines.

Comment: Agree, that's the 'cascade' in action, sadly no easy fix.

Comment: Yes very sad. Thanks though. I will have to figure out an alternate approach.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to override those style attributes in a separate css with `!important`

```
.k-grid td
{
   // UI styles
   color:#000;
}

/* your style */
.k-grid td
{
   // styles
   color:#fff !important;
}
```

Comment: Actually `!important` is not necessary if the specificity of the second selector is equal or higher and the rule comes after the original one.