# Removing Kendo UI Window's dynamic styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I'm trying to remove the default styles that are Kendo UI's window popup styles. They are currently being dynamically put into the style tag and are changeable from the kendoWindow() method.

However I want them to be removed so that I can use my own stylesheet to control the window. Maybe someone has experience with Kendo UI or has an idea to remove those styles so I can begin with standard CSS.

I've tried clearing out the style attribute but it breaks several things within the window that it shouldn't.

```
   $('.k-widget.k-window').attr('style', '');
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343453/disabling-css-rules

Comment: Kendo is getting its inline CSS from JavaScript not CSS. It cannot be overwritten by CSS. Inline CSS wins when it comes to specificity.

Comment: ok so use `!Important`

Comment: If what you want is define your own styling... why do not include the CSS with your own styling after theirs?

Comment: I didn't realize that !important overrules inline styles! Nice answer @CSharper

Answer (score 0):

You can just override any Kendo styles you like:

- By being more specific in your css (see [specificity rules](http://designshack.net/articles/css/what-the-heck-is-css-specificity/))
- Injecting css classes or styles using javascript or JQuery (ie. addClass)

Comment: Actually the Mozilla Developer Network article you quote for “specificity rules” has many errors: 1) Under "Crescent [ehh?] order of specificity" it claims class, attribute & pseudo-class selectors have increasing specificity; they don't, they are equal (see W3C). 2) The same list omits pseudo-elements completely. 3) Under "Instead of using it, you can" it says "By indicating one or more elements before the element you're selecting..… ", then uses the example: div#test span { color: green }. Wrong, that eg is more specific not because of the extra element, but because of the id it contains.

Comment: [Sorry, the MDN article has too many errors to squeeze into one comment!] 4) Under the heading "You should use it when" it says to use !important when "You have a global CSS file that sets visual aspects of your site globally". No, you should still try to use more specific selectors. !important is a last resort. In addition the article is very unclear; eg under "How is it calculated?" it says "The specificity is calculated on the concatenation of the count of each selectors type", but then doesn't explain the "concatenation". And so on; MDN didn't do very well on this one.

Comment: I'll see if I can find a better source. The page can be edited I think(?), so feel free to correct the errors you see there, rather than pasting them here. ;)

Anyway, for his issue only basic specificity rules were required, this page does suffice for that.

Comment: Hmmmm. Thanks for that, I hadn't realised editing MDN was open to all. I might just have a look at doing that.  Though I'd be inclined to rip the whole page out and start again, which the current authors might not like!

Comment: Hey guys, the answer was to stop using Kendo!